# Склонение имени существительного после слова "более"

Tags: склонение, числительные, существительные

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со склонением имени существительного после слова "более".
Проблемное предложение: Гости посетят 2 или более мероприятий (мероприятия) за один день.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Гости посетят **2 или более мероприятия** за один день.*

Имеется в виду: *два мероприятия или более.*

Сравнить:  *Гости посетят **5 или более мероприятий** за один день.*

**Вопрос № 282475**

Добрый день. Бизнес, которым владеют два и более человек (два и более человека?)

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более... управляемое существительное ставится в род. падеже ед. числа: ***два и более человека***. Ср.: **два человека и более**.

Answer (score 1):

Получается так:
*Гости посетят 2 или более [чем 2] мероприятия за один день.*
*Гости посетят 2 или больше мероприятий за один день.*
"Более" так не согласуется с существительным:
*Я съем более печенья.* || Не работает.
*Я съем больше печенья.

Нам нужно более мероприятий.* || Не работает.
*Нам нужно больше мероприятий.*