# Склонение существительного после "более"

Tags: склонение

Помогите, пожалуйста. Фраза "На каждом этаже размещено по 2 или более животного/животных"

Правило говорит, что в таких конструкциях единственное число в родительном падеже [https://orfogrammka.ru/грамматика/сочетания_числительных_с_существительными/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8/) Но для слов на "-ое" звучит как-то странно: 2 или более животного / 3 или более насекомого.

Comment: второе животное, второго животного, по два животных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **[Два насекомых](https://stihi.ru/2018/09/09/4070), муха и пчела.**.. (стихи).  А разве это правильно? Нет!  Надо сказать так: **двое насекомых** (животных, больных). Но в размер не помещается!
2. Странно звучит: **два или более насекомого**? Тогда не надо так говорить.  Скажите так: *двое насекомых или более.* Или так: Двое или более насекомых. Это **особый** случай.
3. Обсуждение темы на форуме: [Склонение имени существительного после слова "более"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471985/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5)  Почему мы выбираем единственное, а не множественное число.
4. Но это для таких сочетаний: ***два или более мероприятия***. А существительные ***насекомое, животное*** имеют грамматическую форму ***прилагательного*** и особую **сочетаемость** с числительными.